# How to group by field then order by different field then limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like:

```
SELECT _threads.*, _messages.*
FROM _threads
LEFT JOIN _messages
ON _threads.thread_id = _messages.message_thread_id
WHERE _threads.thread_servicer_id = 'jG5s2b6TRs'
GROUP BY _threads.thread_customer_id
```

Which returns something like:
[image]

How can i modify the query to be able to group by `thread_customer_id` THEN order by `message_time` and only pick the row with the latest `message_time`.

Comment: Usually if you are using a GROUP BY you want to aggregate the data in some form - what do you want to aggregate on. Also I'm 99% sure you want an INNER JOIN not  LEFT JOIN

Comment: As of now its seems to work for me to grab one row for each customer.

Comment: Ok but what do you want to do for each customer, count the threads?, sum total message, average number of messages per customer? You are not using the aggregation at all. Or to put it another way :-) - what is your query in natural language. ie I want a count of all the customer that have more than 2 message threads?

Comment: I need to grab only the latest message by each customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prequery the threads/messages grouped by customer and get the max posting time per your servicer ID filter.  From that, it will return a single customer/datetime.  THEN, back-join it back to the messages table AGAIN, but only for the matched date/time, then to the thread that matches your servicer ID.. just in case the slim chance of exact same date/time posting of multiple messages under different servers

```
SELECT 
      T2.*, 
      M2.*
   FROM
      ( select T.thread_Customer_id,
               MAX( M.Message_Time ) as LatestPost
           from
              _Threads T
                 JOIN _Messages M
                    ON T.Thread_ID = M.Message_Thread_ID
           where
              T.thread_servicer_id = 'jG5s2b6TRs'
           GROUP BY 
              T.thread_customer_id ) PreMax

      JOIN _Messages M2
         on PreMax.LatestPost = M2.Message_Time

         JOIN _Threads T2
            on M2.Message_Thread_ID = T2.Thread_ID
           AND T2.Thread_Customer_ID = PreMax.Thread_Customer_ID
           AND T2.Thread_Servicer_ID = 'jG5s2b6TRs'

   ORDER BY 
      M2.Message_Time DESC
```

Comment: can always tell the difference between my developer query vs you DBA query ;-)

Comment: @AdrianCornish, but I'm not a DBA, just plenty of experience writing strange queries and mentally understanding models to pull out the crud from all the bloat :)

Answer (score 1):

From extra info in your comments I think this shall provide the result you want

```
SELECT t.*, m.*, MAX(m.message_time)
FROM _threads t
INNER JOIN _messages m
ON t.thread_id = m.message_thread_id
WHERE t.thread_servicer_id = 'jG5s2b6TRs'
GROUP BY t.thread_customer_id
ORDER BY m.message_time
```

Comment: Hey Adrian thanks for you effort, this query orders the who returned results, what i want is for the rows to be grouped by thread_customer_id, and then and then each individual group to be ordered by message_time ASC then take the latest message_time from EACH GROUP.

Comment: @Babiker Add extra fields to the order by query, as in "ORDER BY t.thread_customer_id, m.message_time"